# How to improve the performance of the following code?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, opengl, pyopengl

```py
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
for face in faces:
   for vertex_i in face:
      glVertex3f(*vertices[vertex_i])
glEnd()
```

Is there any way to replace the double *for* loops with a more efficient function/method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the fixed function attributes and define an array of vertex data [`glVertexPointer`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glVertexPointer.html) / [`glEnableClientState`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glEnableClientState.html). In this case you can draw the triangles by [`glDrawElements`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glDrawElements.html).
`indices` has to be an array of the triangle indices and `vertexarray` and array of the coordinate components. For Instance:

Once at initilization:

```py
vertexarray = [c for v in vertices for c in v]
indices = [i for f in faces for i in f]
```

Per frame:

```py
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexarray)
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices)
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

```py
import numpy

vertexarray = numpy.array(vertices, dtype=numpy.float)
indices = numpy.array(faces, dtype=numpy.uint32)
```

```py
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexarray)
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, indices.size, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices)
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
```